# How to Fix: Error in training[, 1:9] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, random-forest

By splitting the dataset via `SplitUplift`, the 2 sets training and validating and also `split.data1` are lists. 
if I try to create the `DualUplift` function, the result is an error

> Error in `contrasts<-(*tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]])` :
>   contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

I tried to change the `SplitUplift` in a data frame by
using:

```r
split.data1<- SplitUplift(data1, 0.5, group = c("train","visit"))        
str(split.data1)        
split.data2 <- data.frame(split.data1)        
str(split.data2)
```

which results in

> Error in training[, 1:9] : incorrect number of dimensions.

```r
read.csv(*Used dataset*)
data1 <- read.csv2(*Used dataset*)
library(tools4uplift)
library(dummies)
set.seed(1988)
group = c("train", "visit")   
split.data1<- SplitUplift(data1, 0.5, group = c("train", "visit"))
str(split.data1)
split.data2 <- data.frame(split.data1)
str(split.data2)
training <- split.data1[[1]]
str(training)
validating <- split.data1[[2]]
"base.tm" <- DualUplift(training, "train", "visit", predictors = colnames(training[,1:9]))
```

I expect that there will be an outcome for the "base.tm" instead of a Error Message